# Sharing data between components in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, components, sharing

I got an array of data in one component which I want to access in another component but cannot get it right

My idea was to just import component one in component two and thought I could access the data in that way but it didnt work.

here is what I got so far ...

**Component 1:**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      info: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "Title One"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Title Two"
        },
```

**Component 2:**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div v-for="item in info" v-bind:key="item.id">
         <div>{{ item.title }} </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import ComponentOne from "../views/ComponentOne ";

export default {
  components: {
    ComponentOne 
  },  But after this I am a bit lost
```

Can anyone point my to the right direction it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What about Vuex?

Comment: Maybe. Are there some example somewhere? Seems like such a trivial task to access your data ...

Answer (score 2):

In order to access shared data, the most common way is to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). I'll get you going with the super basics with a module system as it does take a little reading.

`npm install vuex --save`

Create new folder called `store` in the `src` directory.

src/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import example from './modules/example'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    example // replace with whatever you want to call it
  }
})
```

src/main.js

```
// add to your imports
import store from './store/index'
...

// Change your Vue instance init
new Vue({
  router,
  store, // <--- this bit is the thing to add
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

/src/store/modules/example.js

```
// initial state
const state = {
  info: []
}

// getters
const getters = {}

// actions
const actions = {
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
  set (state, newState) {
    state.info.splice(0)
    state.info.push.apply(state.info, newState)
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

To update the store when you get info, from any component you can use `this.$store.commit('example/set', infoArray)` where the first parameter follows the pattern of `module name/mutation function name`, and the second parameter is the 'new state' that you want updated.

To access the data from the store, you can access it from your components as a computed property:

```
computed: {
  info () {
    return this.$store.state.example.info
  }
}
```

Obviously you can use getters and actions and other stuff, but this will get you going and you can read up and modify the Vuex store once you get comfortable and understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if you do not want to use any other state management like `vuex` then you can share with the use of mixins.

Well, you can achieve it with the use of `Vue.mixins`.

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the `mixins` will be “mixed” into the component’s own options.

Mixins official [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

Hope this helps!